# Open-Dolphin status at August 24 2015

Tags: java, groovy, gpars, opendolphin

What is the status of this library at August 24, 2015? The [web page](http://open-dolphin.org) has some months without moves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow does not maintain the Open-Dolphin project.

Comment: What does "maintain" mean in this context?

Comment: Open-Dolphin is a powerful library, there are groups around the world with the eyes on her, and as far as i know, has an elite group of developers. I don't know what you mean with your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenDolphin is in 1.0-RC1.

The web page is to be replaced soon with a totally new one. There was not much point in making changes to the old one.

Comment: For the updated web site, please have a look at http://dolphin-platform.io/